# Tightness vs Equi-integrability, Prokorov

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, uniform-integrability, equicontinuity

I am a bit confused by this Theorem in the book 'Optimal Transport
for Applied Mathematicians' of Santambrogio. This question concerns absolutely continuous (w.r.t Lebesgue) probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

The theorem says that given a sequence $\{\rho_n\}$ of weakly converging probability densities (i.e convergence against $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ functions), if the sequence is equi-integrable (which I think people also call uniformly integrable) defined as  [equi-integrable definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIs1X.png), then the sequence weakly converges (up to a subsequence) in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ [Theorem equi-integrable implies L1 convergence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAupP.png).

Why I'm confused : I don't understand why we need the weak convergence in the statement of the theorem. Surely : equi-integrability implies tightness, then Prokhorov theorem implies the weak convergence?

What am I missing? How is this strategy different to obtianing convergence via tightness + Prokhorov theorem?

Comment: Equi-integrability coupled with weak convergence (in the sense of probability measures) implies weak convergence in $L^1$ of the *whole* sequence, not just up to a subsequence.

Comment: @Michh Okok. But doesnt equi-integrability imply weak convergence (in the sense of probability measures) so why say coupled ?

Comment: Equi-integrability does not imply weak convergence: just take $\rho_{2n} = f$ and $\rho_{2n+1} = g$. Your reasoning at the end is correct though: equi-integrability implies tightness.

Comment: @Michh ok so Equi-integrability implies tightness, which by Prokhorov implies weak convergence (in the sense of probability measures) up to a sub-sequence.